# JHipster - prod build is not working correctly

Tags: jhipster

I worked a lot on my JHipster project. After 3 weeks I packaged the project again and tried to run the war.
The war is running but the problem is that there is a problem with the frontend. It shows the Hipster error "An error has occured :-(...".
The console logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at Module.503
```

I'm just confused because when I run npm start, everything works. I didn't change the webpack or package.json. I'm using the newest JH version.

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace?  JHipster apps are tested in prod through the CI, so most likely the issue has to do with a custom change after generation

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of it. It's not a JHipster generator problem. the posted snippet is the stacktrace... How can it be that nom start is working but the prod build not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. We are using index files in Angular. The order of the exports was not correct. We exported the module first and the module tried to access data from the index which was not exported at this time.

Hope I could help you.